# Does neural network work this way in general?

Tags: neural-networks

***Note:** My knowledge of ML is very limited, but I appreciate detailed technical answers as long as they are wrapped in a more general understanding. I also know this is somewhat of a soft question, and I only appreciate any suggestions (as long as they're specific) to move it to another more appropriate forum, or other tags; this one is the [most active](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130524/which-stack-exchange-website-for-machine-learning-and-computational-algorithms) and best for ML imo.*

In a recent video called [*"But what is a neural network REALLY?"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBpPjjhJGhk&list=WL&index=15), presumably named after [the 3Blue1Brown series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk), it is claimed that why neural networks actually work comes down to the fact that we are fitting a sum of a bunch of piecewise linear functions (ReLU:s) to the data. More precisely each neuron is represented by a function

$n_k=w_{k+2}\max(0,w_kx+b_k)+b_{k+1}$

and we sum more and more of these neurons up fit the data (points in 2d here).

**Questions:**

**(i)** Is this essentially how ANN:s and deep learning works in general and then what more precisely is the mysterious black box? Is it why backpropagation works as well as it does? (but that is essentially through gradient descent right?)

**(ii)** I assume that the parameters $w_i$ are represented as weights in the network, but what is the network interpretation/representation of the $b_i$:s?

**The reason of question (i)** is that it is often argued that we don't really know why neural networks work and it is referred to as a bit of a *black box* (examples include the book *Artificial Intelligence* by Melanie Mitchell, but many more). I've also heard that Naftali Tishby et al.'s work on the Information Bottleneck, which I confess I have to read up more on, is an attempt to "unlock" this box. I also read the first answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339106/do-we-know-how-deep-neural-networks-work), where it reads: "Once we have set the values of the parameters we can try to look at what the neural network is doing by considering those building blocks to understand the inner logic of the system. This is what we sometimes are unable to do [...]". But it seems to me that summing up piecewise linear functions and minimizing the error via backpropagation is an explanation. We don't usually call other regression methods, such as LSE black boxes. Basically, if one were to form research questions about this what would they include? "Why does part ___ of a network of type ___ work as well as it does?" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking *"what is the black box"*. First of all, not only neural networks are "black boxes", but this would be the case also for simple machine learning algorithms like linear regression or decision trees if they have *a lot* of parameters. You are correct that there is nothing mysterious about piecewise linear functions, or even linear functions packed in the sigmoids. The problem is when you have *a lot* of such functions and they all interact with each other.

Look once again at the popular graphic from Wikipedia:

[image]

Each arrow means that the output of the previous function goes as input to the next one. Even for as simple a neural network as above, you wouldn't be able to give a simple answer to the question "ok, so how does it work?".  It works by applying the mathematical functions to the inputs, but *without doing any calculations by hand* could you approximately guess what it predicts for a given input..? Likely not. If I asked you what should you change in the neural network so that it returns a specific prediction, you wouldn't have a simple answer to that question.

Say that you have an engineering degree. It would mean that you "know" engineering and know how things work. However, this wouldn't mean that if someone gave you a space shuttle and some tools, but no manuals whatsoever, you could easily backward engineer how it works and "understand it". With your engineering skills, you wouldn't be able to fix it or fly it. It would be easy to learn how individual components work, but you wouldn't be able to produce a realistic mental model of a whole space shuttle. Even in the case of Nasa, you have whole teams dedicated to individual components rather than one engineer who "knows how it works".

Comment: But, ime, we don't go on about how we don't know how e.g. simple linear regression works (even in rather complicated situations). Also, we don't generally say that how a space shuttle works is a black box or a mystery. I might not comprehend systems of that many parts on my own, but I can have confidence that "we" understand it. We can of course get more philosophical and ask why emergence in complex systems happens in general: Just because I know the rules of a cellular automata, does not mean I can predict it. I just thought there were in a sense more known unknowns in deep learning.

Comment: If the mystery is mostly all hyped up, and it's not really more mysterious than any other parametric regression, say linear regression in many dimensions, then I'm fine with that I guess.

Comment: @ciru_4011 "black box" is used here for a complicated system consisting of many moving parts, where understanding each of the individual parts does not make you understand how the system works as a whole.

Comment: Sure, and this is true for most what we call 'emergent phenomena'. I guess I didn't see why we're often dis-proportionally calling it mysterious compared to other methods of regression, i.e. if we know how all the parts work, we know what and how we're optimizing it, and exactly how the training works. I guess I didn't see the resulting optimization that happens as something emergent or chaotic, but as a more predictable result, similar to simple linear regression, i.e. many interacting parts doesn't necessarily give complexity either.(I'll leave a little room before accepting your answer.)